# How to create black and white transparent overlapping histograms using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, textures, histogram

I used ggplot2 to create two transparent overlapping histograms.

```
test = data.frame(condition = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 500), value = rep(-1, 1000))
test[1:500,]$value = rnorm(500)
test[501:1000,]$value = rnorm(500) + 2

fig = ggplot(test, aes(x = value, fill = condition)) +
      #scale_fill_grey() +
      geom_histogram(position = "identity", alpha = .5)
fig
```

The resulting plot looks great, but it's in color.  I need a grayscale or black/white plot.

Using "scale_fill_grey()" results in a plot with transparency that is very difficult to "read".

Ideally, I would like a black/white plot that uses texture instead of color, for instance, cross hatching: "///" for one condition, "\\\" for the other condition, resulting in "XXX" when the bars overlap.  Is this possible?

Comment: To my knowledge, texturing is not possible with `ggplot2`.

Comment: Is it possible to use texturing with the function hist() or truehist() (from the MASS library)?

Answer (score 14):

How about this (no texturing still)?

```
fig = ggplot(test, aes(x = value, fill = condition)) +
    geom_histogram(position = "identity", alpha = .8) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("grey20", "grey60")) + theme_bw()
fig
```

[image]